# JPA 2 / Hibernate / MySql GenerationType.AUTO

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When i'm using GenerationType.IDENTITY or GenerationType.AUTO for my table id and i persist an entity inside a transaction, data are instantanely inserted, and this before the transaction end !!!

I tried to change whith GenerationType.TABLE, generate and execute the new associated DDL in my MYSQL database, and now it's working.
Is anyone can explain me why?

Extract:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

        ...
}


@Repository
public class EntityDaoServiceImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

        @Transactional
    public void testFooCreation() {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            em.persit(foo);
            //at this point with the AUTO or IDENTITY strategie, 
            //i ve got an effective insert in base otherwise with the TABLE strategie, 
            //the insert is effective at the end of my transaction (the excepted behavior)
    }

}
```

Comment: `i ve got an effective insert in base` how do you check that ? (addind a dummy `System.out.println("Breakpoint");` just after the `em.persist();` . Put a breakpoint there and look at your table Foo with an external tool to see if the new line is really in your DB seems a good way to do it. Did you do that ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected, as no one said that the inserts are not made in DB until the transaction is not finished. The idea is that the JPA provider (Hibernate in your case) decides itself when to make a flush to the database, and it seems that in the case of `GenerationType.TABLE` it decides to make it in early on. BUT, because that flush is made, that does not mean that the transaction is finished/commited: after persist you/or the JPA provider could rollback the transaction, and the row will not remain in DB.

PS: I hope you have some background about transactions (google for transaction isolation level) and/or MySql's storage engines (InnoDB is a transactional engine, and MyIsam is not).

Comment: I'm using InnoDB for the transactional engine, but with GenerateType.AUTO, just after the persist, the line is inserted, i m always in the transaction and if i kill my process, the line is still in dataBase, i don't have any rollback.

Comment: Have you tried the throw a RuntimeException right after persisting the entity, instead of killing the process? Have you tried to watch Hibernate's logs, in order to see if/how the transaction begins and rolls back/commits?

Comment: Thank you so much for all those precisions Andrei and Ben75, for me i was confused about data in the persistence context and flushed data from persitence context to database, but ok i get it now. So i looked away, and i have got the answer !! I was using the InnoDb dialect for the hibernate.dialect propertie BUT my table was created whithout ENGINE=InnoDB !!!!!!!!